# Techniques around administrative/super user code being exposed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, marionette

When building a single page application, in my example with Backbone w/ Marionette, how does one approach administrative/super user sections of code.  For example if I build a site that has an admin section that can delete users, manage account details from a financial perspective, etc, technically an attacker can view the code.  Additionally an attacker could see the precompiled templates from a visual standpoint.  While I understand you can compress the code/obfuscate , that really isn't a solution.  Is this just something that's considered a pitfall when developing SPA's?  IE one just needs to make absolutely sure the API is secure, etc.  If something isn't secure, essentially a roadmap is already provided to a potential attacker...

Comment: Is there any reason to send non-admin users code related to doing admin stuff in the first place? Why not just send basic users the basic stuff, and send admin users the admin stuff?

Comment: Typically with the single page applications all the code is downloaded at once.  Including models, templates, controllers, routers, etc.  It would be interesting to segregate, but I guess that would mean that in essence you would be building two SPA's.  Server rendered code is nice in this respect as the end user has no idea why or how things are being generated.  With client side apps, well, all the code is on the client side.

Comment: Yeah, I have dealt with more SPAs than I care to think about and have never run into this problem, so it seems strange to me. I never thought of loading everything up front as being a prerequisite for SPAs, though. I load a lot of the rarely-used stuff on demand (including admin stuff).

Comment: I assume you're using something like requireJS?  In my case I'm leveraging the asset pipeline in ruby on rails.  Additionally, are you talking in experience with Backbone Marionette?

Comment: requireJS, yes. Backbone, no. If Backbone really doesn't allow LOD that makes another nice excuse for me never to bother learning it, though. ;)

Comment: Does it matter? Code is code, who cares who sees it? The important thing is data, and I assume your data isn't stored client-side. All the data which is actually sensitive needs to be stored behind authentication, this is no different in a SPA than it is with a traditional website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well code for the interface really isn't important: it's javascript anyway, so a malicious user could build his own, or simply generate the required API calls.

In addition, the only thing you'd be giving a "roadmap" for is API endpoints, which tend to be easy to guess (e.g. managing users usually goes through the "users" endpoint). In addition, these endpoints are often known: a user could edit his own account by hitting the "users" endpoint, while an admin could edit all users. The API call would be the same (or very similar) and the credentials/authorization would be verified on the server (which, theoretically, the attacker wouldn't have access to).

Your question is close to "how do I achieve security by obscurity?". I know that's not what you're asking, but its not far off. There shouldn't be an issue with an attacker being able to see the admin code path or API calls, because there shouldn't be anything special about them.

But as you said in your question, you absolutely MUST validate/authorize everything on the server. If you don't treat all data coming from the user as hostile or tampered with, you'll have a bad time...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the well rounded answer David.